# More advanced way to describe a country has many resources

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

My question is: Instead of "this country has many resources", what can I say? This country is abundant in many resources?

Comment: If you're looking for alternate words to describe an idea, "resources" is not the tag you are looking for.  "Synonyms" or "word-definition" might be more appropriate.  More to the point though, this verges very closely on being a question on writing advice, rather than on english usage. If you are looking for a single word that means the thing you are describing, say so and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: You might find this Stack Exchange site useful for future questions: [ell.se].

Answer (score 7):

Resource-rich is a good, short adjective phrase that describes a country that is rich in resources.

Comment: Thank you! Can I say "this region is resource-rich in gas"?

Comment: You could, but it might be more appropriate to say "This region is rich in gas resources", or if you're referring to gas as in petrol, you could say "this region is petrol-rich" to indicate a large amount of petrol belongs to the region.  "Gas-rich" would work, but sounds a little awkward and informal.

Comment: I wasn't aware that *petrol* comes out of the ground: surely the natural product is oil, from which petrol is produced?

Comment: Yes.  Oil would be the actual material that comes out of the ground.  I didn't think Petrol would be objected to, because it is still a resource. Just a refined resource.  But technically if you want to say that the country specifically has the natural resource of Oil, you would say exactly that. It is "Oil-rich" or "Rich in oil."

Comment: Word choice is one of my stronger areas.  You are quite welcome.

Comment: I lately came across a new expression which might hold the similar meaning. The country is richly endowed with mineral deposits. So, "be richly endowed with" can indicate same meaning. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct.  "richly endowed" has the same meaning in this case as "rich with".

Answer (score 3):

**A Resource-Enriched Country** can be used here.

Comment: A good general term for a country that is rich in various resources.

Answer (score 1):

You might say - this country has a **wealth of resources**.

Answer (score 0):

You could say [**resource-laden country**](http://articles.latimes.com/2006/jul/20/opinion/le-thursday20.5) or *This country is [**richly endowed**](http://www.stabroeknews.com/2012/opinion/letters/01/26/government-and-ngos-should-formulate-a-national-plan-for-the-elderly/) with resources*.

> laden: filled with a great quantity